# How do I extend Html.ValidationMessage so that I can include an image as the error?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I would like to reduce the following code. The below code works, however it is not very tidy etc.

```
    <label for="Name">Name:</label><%= Html.TextBox("Name")%><% 
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.ValidationMessage("Name"))) {
        string Error = HtmlRemoval.StripTags(Html.ValidationMessage("Name")); %>
        <img src="Error.gif" alt="Error" title="<%= Error %>" /><%
    }
    %>
```

I have read that I need to extend the Html helper so that I can return an image instead of the text containing the default  element and textual error.

I can't seem to find any articles or general advice on how I would accomplish this.  I am still very new to ASP.NET MVC.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can extend HtmlHelper like:

```
public static class CustomHtmlHelper {

  public static string ValidationImage(this HtmlHelper helper, string name) {
    if (helper.ViewData.ModelState[name] == null || helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors == null) {
      return String.Empty;
    }
    TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("img");
    tag.Attributes.Add("src", "Error.gif");
    tag.Attributes.Add("alt", "Error");
    tag.Attributes.Add("title", helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors[0].ErrorMessage);
    return tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
  }

}
```

Then in your page import the class containing the extension method

```
<%@ Import Namespace="CustomHtmlHelperNamespace" %>
```

Then add the following to your page:

```
<label for="Name">Name:</label>
<%= Html.TextBox("Name")%>
<% Html.ValidationImage("Name") %>
```

For more on extending HtmlHelper try [here](http://www.asp.net/Learn/mvc-videos/video-402.aspx) but basically this extends HtmlHelper, checks the ViewState for a an error on the value parsed in name ("Name" in your case) and if it contains an error generates the HTML needed to render the image.  The title attribute for the image will contain the validation message for field "Name"

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the Html Helper to add a method by making a class like below. Not 100% this is what you're asking, but here goes:

```
public class HtmlHelperExtensions {

    public static string GetMeSomething(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        //... Do things here. ...
    }
}
```

Once you have something like that, you can call Html.GetMeSomething, and it will return a string or whatever you declare your return type as.

Comment: That should be a static method.

Answer (score 1):

Rolling you own ValidationMessage helper to render an image tag may be your best bet... The built-in helper will render a tag such as

```
<span class="field-validation-error">You must specify a username.</span>
```

so if you aren't going to change this you're left to CSS and/or jQuery tricks to do the dirty work.

I'm not aware of a *pure* use if CSS to do your job, but if you can handle having your error message span within a DIV tag, you could try something like:

```
.field-validation-error
{
    background: url(x.gif) no-repeat;
    padding-left:10px;
    color: #ff0000;
}

<div style="width:10px; height:10px; overflow:hidden;">
    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("username") %>
</div>
```

For a 10x10 gif, this will hide the text, but it will be within a block element and without your error message title/"tooltip." Not exactly the best solution. I would check the code for the ValidationMessage method in the MVC source and consider adapting your own to render it exactly as needed, or again, there's Javascript to do the trickery.

**Edit**: Just for fun I decided to test my own Validation Message helper, starting from the MVC source code. It's dirty (hard-coded path to image), but a working example. In this case it requires you to pass in the validation message - I've omitted some code where it optionally displays the default built-in message.

```
public static string MyValidationMessage(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string modelName, string validationMessage)
{
    if (modelName == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("modelName");

    if (!htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(modelName))
        return null;

    ModelState modelState = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState[modelName];
    ModelErrorCollection modelErrors = (modelState == null) ? null : modelState.Errors;
    ModelError modelError = ((modelErrors == null) || (modelErrors.Count == 0)) ? null : modelErrors[0];

    if (modelError == null) 
        return null;

    return "<img src=\"../../Content/x.gif\" alt=\"Error\" title=\"" + validationMessage + "\" />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Great answer by David Glenn. Many thanks for putting me on the right track with creating custom Html helpers in Mvc.**

But, there are a couple issues with David's extension out of the box (in MVC3 w/Razor):

- Returning just a string will not work; it will actually display the string, tags and all, unless you wrap it on the view (UI) with MvcHtmlString.Create(). A more elegant approach is to change the return type of the helper function as an MvcHtmlString. You could also overload the Helper functions to accommodate both return types as well.
- If you are doing additional errors on
  a single model field, such as a RegEx
  check, etc., the helper method will
  fail because the initial "If..Then.."
  fails to check for an error count;
  just checking if it "Is Null" will
  not suffice. The Errors object will
  not be null, but all of it's
  properties will on the non-failing
  fields.

So below is the CustomHtmlHelper class refactored to accommodate for the above two issues and also injects the correct css class name:

```
#Region "Imports"

Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

#End Region

Namespace Laddawn.Web.Mvc.Extensions

    Public Module CustomHtmlHelpers

        <Extension()>
        Public Function ValidationImage(ByVal helper As HtmlHelper, ByVal name As String) As MvcHtmlString

            If helper.ViewData.ModelState(name) Is Nothing _
            OrElse helper.ViewData.ModelState(name).Errors Is Nothing _
            OrElse helper.ViewData.ModelState(name).Errors.Count = 0 Then
                Return MvcHtmlString.Empty
            End If

            Dim tag As New TagBuilder("img")

            With tag
                .Attributes.Add("src", "/Content/Images/Mobile/alert.png")
                .Attributes.Add("alt", helper.ViewData.ModelState(name).Errors(0).ErrorMessage)
                .Attributes.Add("title", helper.ViewData.ModelState(name).Errors(0).ErrorMessage)
                .Attributes.Add("class", HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageCssClassName)
            End With

            Return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing))

        End Function

    End Module

End Namespace
```

In your Css file, create a class as such:

```
img.field-validation-error
{
    vertical-align:         text-bottom;
    margin-left:            5px;
}
```

Now your Css can manipulate the image separately from the massage css too.

Notes: Don't forget to change the image path to suit the needs of your project. This is another area where you could potentially add an additional parameter for imagePath and use a default in the helper method if one is not passed in.

Apologies for the VB version (for you C# developers), my current project is all VB/NET and if you want to use the above code, just use the converter over at Telerik (http://converter.telerik.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, my custom validation image helper class will not work with client side validation.

If anyone wants to take a crack at a version that can/will support client side validation, have at it!!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Ed's answer, this is so it can work with Models:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationImageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        string propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string name = helper.AttributeEncode(helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName));

        if (helper.ViewData.ModelState[name] == null || 
            helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors == null || 
            helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors.Count == 0)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("span");
        tag.Attributes.Add("class", "field-validation-error");
        tag.Attributes.Add("data-valmsg-for", name);
        tag.Attributes.Add("data-valmsg-replace", "true");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
```

I was rendering into a span.. the same way that MVC renders it. I have my background image set in the CSS class. Example:

```
@Html.ValidationImageFor(x => x.FieldNameHere)
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The best would be that MVC developers change the type of ModelError.ErrorMessage to an MvcHtmlString or its new counterpart in .NET4 (HtmlString)